# Spark, HiveContext, ThriftServer - Table persistence

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have configured data SparkStreaming. I would like to persist this data for a variety of goals:

- exposing for Tableau (It requires thriftServer, while thriftServer
  requires hiveContext).
- sometimes I would like to be able to update some data.

Where is data kept in HiveContext? In memory? On the local disk? Is it provided by thriftServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could persist your DataFrames from spark to a hive table by doing:
`yourDataFrame.saveAsTable("YourTableName")`

If you want to insert data to existing table you could use:
`yourDataFrame.writer().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("YourTableName")`

This will saves your DataFrame on a persistent Hive table. the location of this table will be dependent on the configuration in your `hive-site.xml`.

By default, if you are testing locally, the location will be on your local disk on the location `/user/hive/warehouse/YourTableName`

If you are using Spark with Hive on Yarn/HDFS then the table will be saved on HDFS on the location defined by the property `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` in your hive-site.xml configuration file

Hope that will help :)

Comment: Yes, it helped.  However, default location for saving tables is local disk. Am I ok ?  It may be also HDFS, then I must configure HDFS. Is it true ? Can you give me link to tutorial about configuring HDFS for thriftServer and spark App ? What is relation between apache spark and apache hive?

Comment: You need to configure your spak to use Yarn/HDFS: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html . and then configure spark thrift server as explained here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#distributed-sql-engine

Comment: Apache spark uses the capabilities of Apache Hive to parse the sql statements, and the thrift server itself is somehow a hiveserver whose engine is Spark. please refer to this answer for more details :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36189239/1314742

Comment: yarn is conneted with HDFS ? I mean, if is it possible to use hdfs without yarn ?

Comment: Yes you could. but I thought since you are using HDFS and Hive, you might be using the full stack Yarn/HDFS/Hive/Spark/.... :)

Comment: Is it difficult to cache table in **ThritftServer** ?

Comment: I think the answer of @Erica cover this. Also I m not sure if I understood the caching you mention, you mean like store the results in a temporary table which will be available just for the execution time?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to cache data on memory using

your_hive_context.cacheTable("table_name")

The Thrift Server access to a global-context that contains all the table, even the temporary ones.

If you cache the table Tableau will get the query results faster, but you have to keep running the Spark Batch application.

I did not find yet a way to update some of the data without opening a new HiveContext.

Comment: Ok, Could you tell me how Hive store my data ? Maybe goo idea is to use Cassandra in place of hive ?  "I did not find yet a way to update some of the data without opening a new HiveContext." What does it mean ? In my case  beeline can see newly inserted data.

Comment: Well, Hive store data on disk. The use of Cassandra with Spark Streaming is very common. 
_"I did not find yet a way to update some of the data without opening a new HiveContext."_ means that once you opened an HiveContext submitting the application, Hive accesses the same "snapshot" of the tables; even if they actually are getting new data from a Spark Streaming application.