# Spark SQL: how does it tell hive to run query on spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

As rightly pointed out here: 
[Spark SQL query execution on Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188516/spark-sql-query-execution-on-hive)

Spark SQL when running through HiveContext will make SQL query use the spark engine.

How does spark SQL setting *`hive.execution.engine=spark`* tell hive to do so?

Note this works automatically, we do not have to specify this in ***hive-site.xml*** in the conf directory of spark.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 independent projects here

1. [Hive on Spark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7292) -  Hive project that integrates Spark as an additional engine.
2. [Spark SQL](http://spark.apache.org/sql/) - Spark module that makes use of the Hive code.

`HiveContext` belongs to the 2nd and `hive.execution.engine` is a property of the 1st.

Comment: So this means that spark sql query gets transformed into RDD's then runs on Hive physical data (may use hive sql parser & hive metastore for transforming the query to physical plan) ?

Comment: There isn't really such thing as "Hive phisical data". There are different file formats supported by Hive that may be supported by other data engines as well.